# Search in a Doubly-Linked List founds members multiple times

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm working through the exercises from PPPC++ and I have a List class that holds multiple gods with their attributes.

Ex: {Thor, Norse, Chariot, Mjolnir} or {Hera, Greek, chariot, pomegranate}
where Thor is Norse god and Hera is a Greek god.

I'm trying to write the code to find the pointers that point to all the gods that are Greek.

And I don't get why Hera is found twice and Ares if found 4 times.
What's wrong?
Thanks!

```
found 0x5586b65353f0 Poseidon
found 0x5586b6535350 Athena
found 0x5586b65351d0 Hera
found 0x5586b65351d0 Hera
found 0x5586b6534f50 Ares
found 0x5586b6534f50 Ares
found 0x5586b6534f50 Ares
found 0x5586b6534f50 Ares
found 0x5586b6534eb0 Zeus
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct God
{
    God(const string &n, const string &m, const string &v, const string &w)
        : name{n}, mythology{m}, vehicle{v}, weapon{w} {}

    string name;
    string mythology;
    string vehicle;
    string weapon;
};

class Link
{
public:
    God god; 
    Link(const string &n, const string &m, const string &v, const string &w, Link *p = nullptr, Link *s = nullptr)
        : god{n, m, v, w}, prev{p}, succ{s} {}
    Link *insert(Link *n);                 // insert n before this object
    Link *find_mythology(const string &s); // find s in list

    Link *next() const { return succ; }
    Link *previous() const { return prev; }

private:
    Link *prev;
    Link *succ;
};

Link *Link::insert(Link *n) // insert n before this object; return n
{
    if (n == nullptr)
        return this;
    if (this == nullptr)
        return n;
    n->succ = this;     // this object comes after n
    if (prev)           // if prev of this (object) is not zero - meaning there's a Link object before this object (or p)
        prev->succ = n; // perv->succ
    n->prev = prev;     // this object’s predecessor becomes n’s predecessor
    prev = n;           // n becomes this object’s predecessor
    return n;           // returns n(the new element) which is before the top node
}
Link *Link::find_mythology(const string &s) // find s in list;
{
    Link *p = this;
    while (p)
    {
        if (p->god.mythology == s)
            return p;
        p = p->succ; // move to the next node
    }
    return nullptr; // return nullptr for “not found”
}
void print_all(Link *p)
{
    while (p)
    {
        cout << " " << p->god.name << ", " << p->god.mythology << ", " << p->god.vehicle << ", " << p->god.weapon;
        if (p = p->next()) // moved to the next node
            cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Link *all_gods = new Link{"Zeus", "Greek", "chair", "lightning"};
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Ares", "Greek", "wings", "sword"});
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Odin", "Norse", "Sleipner", "Gungnir"});
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Thor", "Norse", "Chariot", "Mjolnir"});
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Freia", "Norse", "chariot", "Brisingamen"});
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Hera", "Greek", "chariot", "pomegranate"});
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Tyr", "Norse", "chariot", "spear of justice"});
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Athena", "Greek", "chariot", "thunderbolt"});
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Poseidon", "Greek", "the sea", "trident"});

    print_all(all_gods); // cout the type of the 1st element
    cout << "\n\n";

//while (all_gods)
//{
//    Link *p = all_gods->find_mythology("Greek"); // this returns a pointer where it finds a Norse
//     cout << "found " << p << ' ' << p->god.name << '\n';
//   all_gods = all_gods->next();
//}

Link *p = all_gods;
while (p)
{
    if (p->god.mythology == "Greek")
        cout << "found " << p << ' ' << p->god.name << '\n';
    p = p->next();
}
delete[] p;
// here I will still use all_gods before deleting it below
delete all_gods;

print_all(all_gods);
cout << "\n\n";
print_all(p);
cout << "\n\n";
}
```

### Edit

I changed the while loop in main() and now it does what I wanted.

Comment: `this == nullptr` is never true.

Comment: You look for the first "Greek" starting at the first element, then starting at the second element, then starting at the third element, ... If the third element is the first "Greek", how many times will you find it?

Comment: `all_gods = all_gods->next();` -- Good luck in trying to `delete` everything you allocated.

Comment: You're in trouble if the last element isn't what you're looking for, as `p` will be the null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good (though not very OO).

It also seems to be working the way I would expect:

```
// When you start the list is:
//    Poseidon : Athena : Tyr : Hera ......
while (all_gods)
{
    // So first time threw this loop you find: Poseidon
    Link *p = all_gods->find_mythology("Greek");
    cout << "found " << p << ' ' << p->god.name << '\n';

    // Now you are altering the list (and leaking an object.
    // but thats another question).
    //
    
    all_gods = all_gods->next();
    // But you dropped "Poseidon" off the front so the list is now:
    // Athena : Tyr : Hera ......
}
```

So your second time around the loop you print `Athena`. Then you drop Athena from the list so the list is `Tyr : Hera ......`.

So your third time around the loop you will print `Hera` (first Greek god). But then you drop `Tyr` so the list is `Hera ......`.

So the fourth time around the loop you will print `Hera` again as she is still on the list and the first Greek god.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I think I fixed it (edited the main post) with a new while loop and a new pointer which I delete afterwards. I you don't mind asking more questions... how should I make it more OO?

Comment: @Theodore A `List` is an object. A `Link` in the list is own objects but separate from the list. You don't perform `insert()` on a link you perform `insert()` on a list. Also you don't have resource management don't. There is no ownership of the set of Links and you just seem to pass the ownership around via a pointer. The set of `Links` should be owned and managed by a `List` object . When you `find()` don't return a `Link` return a `God` reference. Stop using pointers (we don't do that much in C++ (learn about ownership semantics (shared pointers and containers)).

Comment: Thanks Martin! I'm following the exercises from B. Stroustrup's book. Hopefully after 4 more chapters I'll know more than I know now.